# Outbound Phone Verification With Twillio and Zapier

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, zapier

Just signed up for Twillio paid and want to potentially verify if phone number is valid or not. I've successfully made outbound calls from Zapier through Twillio. Zapier also allows you to take responses and use those as Triggers but that only seems to be working if get an Inbound call through Twillio vs Outbound.

The Zapier Trigger is called "New Call" but only seems to work for Inbound. Does it work for Outbound and if so what do I need to setup differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

I checked on our end and it looks like we've got open feature requests for both the "Verify Number" action and the "New Outbound Call" trigger. If you send me your zapier email address (or write into support and link this answer) we can add you as someone who wants those done. User demand helps us prioritize features and your email lets us notify you if/when the feature is added.

​Let me know if you've got any other questions!

Comment: Great will do. Problem short term obviously.

Comment: yeah, unfortunately we can't fix that directly. If you're comfortable doing some coding, you could use the [Verify API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api) (which is the same one we'd eventually use) in a Code step to make the call on your own.